# How to integrate role based permission in Laravel with Dingo API?

Tags: laravel, dingo-api, entrust

I'm currently studying `Laravel` framework and dingo api. Is there any way to integrate the role based permission using entrust to dingo api?

So for example, I have a route to get all the list of users, but only admin can access this.

So if the user is authenticated, but he's not an admin, he can't access this route.

I tried adding the middleware of entrust to the routes.php but when I tried it on postman, I get a syntax error.

here's my routes.php file:

```
$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'role:admin']], function ($api) {
    $api->get('users', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@index');
    $api->get('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@show');
});
```

Comment: this link will help you to implement the roles https://github.com/karoys/laravel-native-roles-auth

Answer (score 0):

You can group this into different parts as this:

```
$api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function ($api) {
//general routes route goes here
//....
    $api->group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function($api) {
    //admin routes goes here

        $api->get('users', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@index');
        $api->get('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@show');
    });
});
```

This means even though the user is authenticated, the two routes in the new group can only be accessed by the admins.

I hope this is helpful.